# Testing e2e with detox failing to start iPhone simulator, starts Apple TV instead

Tags: ios, react-native, end-to-end, detox

tldr; I have a React Native app, and I am using workspace. I have gone through this [detox getting started](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.GettingStarted.md) document and I now have an e2e folder with 3 files (default), and a configuration in the package.json.

Configuration looks like

```
"detox": {
    "test-runner": "mocha",
    "specs": "e2e",
    "runner-config": "e2e/mocha.opts",
    "configurations": {
        "ios.sim.debug": {
            "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app",
            "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme Staging -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
            "type": "ios.simulator",
            "name": "iPhone 6"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `xcrun simctl list` I get the following list, where iPhone 6 is listed and Booted.

```
== Devices ==
-- iOS 11.4 --
    iPhone 5s (E9D0264C-9257-4BE4-8693-4B7AE6AAE97A) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 6 (099D481A-6F6D-4DC9-A379-16DFAE617CA0) (Booted)
    iPhone 6 Plus (7556F239-06F0-421D-A294-AE15BCF6D64D) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 6s (FB65410A-4654-40BB-88B0-234DF3C191DE) (Shutdown)
...
-- tvOS 11.4 --
    Apple TV (9875527D-A6FC-4BD8-965E-255C910E3ABA) (Shutdown)
    Apple TV 4K (0BF2198F-04AF-49CC-B05C-540BB2FB53AF) (Shutdown)
    Apple TV 4K (at 1080p) (8F14FC95-685B-481C-860F-384CBD880D2B) (Shutdown)
...
```

`detox build --configuration ios.sim.debug` runs fine, but when I run `detox test --configuration ios.sim.debug` or `detox build` or `detox build --reuse` it starts the Apple TV simulator and throws this error

```
detox info 11:47:49: server listening on localhost:51379...
detox info 2: Searching for device matching iPhone 6...
detox info 5: Booting device 9875527D-A6FC-4BD8-965E-255C910E3ABA
detox info 7: Terminating com.local.MyApp...
detox ERR! 7: An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=164):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutting Down, exited with code 164
  1) "before all" hook

  0 passing (9s)
  1 failing

  1) "before all" hook:
     Error: 7: running "/usr/bin/xcrun simctl terminate 9875527D-A6FC-4BD8-965E-255C910E3ABA com.local.MyApp" returned undefined
      at Object.execWithRetriesAndLogs (node_modules/detox/src/utils/exec.js:36:11)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)



child_process.js:615
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/mocha e2e --opts e2e/mocha.opts --configuration ios.sim.debug   --reuse  --grep :android: --invert
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:575:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:612:13)
    at runMocha (/Users/me/code/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:114:6)
    at run (/Users/me/code/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:75:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/code/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:181:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
```

You can see that under `detox info 5:` it starts booting up `9875527D-A6FC-4BD8-965E-255C910E3ABA`, which is the Apple TV Device.

How can I configure detox to start an iPhone simulator instead?

Comment: I don't know if it helps for anyone having same issues, but I had to upgrade applesimutils and clear cache. `brew update && brew upgrade applesimutils` and 
`detox clean-framework-cache && detox build-framework-cache`

Answer (score 3):

`brew update && brew upgrade applesimutils` and `detox clean-framework-cache && detox build-framework-cache` as suggested by Tim Rijavec helped in my case! Hidden in the comments it looked like there is no solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me what running both these command in the terminal

```
brew update && brew upgrade applesimutils
```

and

```
detox clean-framework-cache && detox build-framework-cache
```

Then I re-ran my detox build and detox test commands and it still did not work. So then I ran.

```
open -a simulator
```

On my mac and this booted up a couple instances of the ios simulators that were backed up so it looks like something weird was happening that was causing the simulator not to actually boot. After that running detox test started booting the simulator properly.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade detox to version 19.7.1 worked for me ([reference](https://bytemeta.vip/index.php/repo/wix/Detox/issues/3331)).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue after upgrading to Xcode 15. Detox was unable to launch the target on a simulator:

```
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3): Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation. found nothing to terminate
```

Issue was resolved after I upgraded AppleSimUtils

```
brew tap wix/brew
brew update
brew install wix/applesimutils
```

and updated the the latest Detox version in my dev dependecies

```
yarn add detox --latest --dev
```